# css: column-count property - how to modify it with css to modify the number of items in each column?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, dom

There is a http://jsfiddle.net/woyy389L/3 link for visualization of this question , it contains 4 columns and the columns are as 5+5+5+2=17 items in this `ul`.

Can it be done as 5+4+4+4 items with css fix only without breaking the html structure?

Displayed properly in Firefox and Chrome.

The css code is:

```
ul{
   -webkit-column-count: 4;
    -moz-column-count: 4;    
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Html code is:

```
<ul>
        <li><a class="myclass" href="#"><span>bbb</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="myclass" href="#"><span>bbb</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="myclass" href="#"><span>bbb</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="myclass" href="#"><span>bbb</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="myclass" href="#"><span>bbb</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="myclass" href="#"><span>bbb</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="myclass" href="#"><span>bbb</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="myclass" href="#"><span>bbb</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="myclass" href="#"><span>bbb</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="myclass" href="#"><span>bbb</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="myclass" href="#"><span>bbb</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="myclass" href="#"><span>bbb</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="myclass" href="#"><span>bbb</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="myclass" href="#"><span>bbb</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="myclass" href="#"><span>bbb</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="myclass" href="#"><span>bbb</span></a></li>
        <li><a class="myclass" href="#"><span>bbb</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Thank you.

Comment: don't think this is possible as it will always fill up the columns from left to right so as long as the first column accepts 5 values the second and third will also have 5 and the fourth will get the remainder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware that's not currently possible with just HTML/CSS alone.

Chris Coyier's CSS Tricks gives a good overview of what's currently possible: http://css-tricks.com/guide-responsive-friendly-css-columns/

For you to achieve what you're after you would have to either alter your HTML or use jQuery to insert closing and opening `ul` tags at the point you require and style it accordingly.